# anacondaの仮想環境エラー

Tags: python, anaconda

Ubuntu18.04上でanacondaを使って仮想環境を作成すると以下のようなエラーが発生します。
何か解決策はないでしょうか？環境は作られるのですが、PATHが変な位置にあるみたいです。

**入力**

```
conda create -n t15 python=3.6
```

**出力**

```
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/test'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.

(tf1.13) user@eins:~$ conda create -n t15 python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/t15

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.6


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/linux-64::ca-certificates-2019.11.27-0
  certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2019.11.28-py36_0
  libedit            pkgs/main/linux-64::libedit-3.1.20181209-hc058e9b_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/linux-64::libffi-3.2.1-hd88cf55_4
  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
  ncurses            pkgs/main/linux-64::ncurses-6.1-he6710b0_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1d-h7b6447c_3
  pip                pkgs/main/linux-64::pip-19.3.1-py36_0
  python             pkgs/main/linux-64::python-3.6.9-h265db76_0
  readline           pkgs/main/linux-64::readline-7.0-h7b6447c_5
  setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-42.0.2-py36_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/linux-64::sqlite-3.30.1-h7b6447c_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/linux-64::tk-8.6.8-hbc83047_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/linux-64::wheel-0.33.6-py36_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/linux-64::xz-5.2.4-h14c3975_4
  zlib               pkgs/main/linux-64::zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: \ WARNING conda.core.path_actions:verify(963): Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.
  environment location: /home/user/.conda/environments.txt

done
Executing transaction: | WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(52): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/t15
  registry file: /home/user/.conda/environments.txt
done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate t15
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate
```

Comment: owner が root になっていそうな予感がします。`ls -lahd /home/user/.conda/environments.txt` の結果を質問文に追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: その辺がぐちゃぐちゃになってました。めんどくさかったので ubuntu ごと入れ直しました。

Comment: どこかのタイミングで誤って `sudo` 付きでコマンドを実行してしまったのかもしれないですね。